# SP2013: Attach a workflow to a custom list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, custom

I'm starting to work quite a bit more on Sharepoint - and using a lot of custom workflows. Many of them are the same just on different sites.

Is it in any way possible to export a workflow and attach it to a list at a later time?

Many of the workflows are interacting with different lists on the same site, so building them everytime from scratch is quite time consuming.

I'm thinking of saving the lists as templates and then attaching the workflows afterwards - I'm hoping this will be possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231590.aspx) article, and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn518136.aspx) one. I think the latter one will satisfy your needs as it is possible to associate a workflow to a list at runtime. Depending on your approach you choose between JSOM, CSOM or SSOM.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not what I was hoping for but I guess it will have to do :-)

//M